# Are appindicators and notifyosd useful for other than Ubuntu's Gnome users?

Tags: gnome, indicator, notification

Are applications that use NotifyOSD and AppIndicators compatible with general Gnome or would e.g. a user of another distribution first need to install some Ubuntu libraries to have the same experience?

In case, what are Gnome's default notification and indicator systems? Developing Gnome applications, what should I use/implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application indicators require another library, so you would have to follow the guides for them on the [ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators). However, they also support a fall-back mode, so they will still work on standard GNOME.

However, [NotifyOSD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD) is just another implementation of a standard notification spec, so nothing changes here.
On GNOME the notification system has a different implementation, but it's the same underlying library - so it's code once, run anywhere.

*In response to your comment:*

- No, standard GNOME applications will not adapt to using application indicators, for no other reason than that (if we are honest here) the GNOME developers don't really like Canonical/Ubuntu, and reject just about anything (most of the time) they (Canonical/the Ubuntu community) produce. For this reason, Canonical has to patch GNOME applications, or third party developers have to create replacements, that honestly should just be pushed upstream, but are blocked by the pointless dam that upstream has in place.

Comment: So, standard Gnome applications won't adapt these kind of application indicators? E.g. gnome-system-monitor won't get indicators in Ubuntu but we need to use/wait for a 3rd party [one](https://launchpad.net/indicator-sysmonitor)? Cheers!